# Adding the total value of 5 functions together to print a result on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 5 functions like the one shown below. What I would like to do is once the user has slid each bar to a position, for the combined total of all 5 bars to print out a message.

Depending on what total is reached, would depend what message is shown. For example, if the total of all 5 slide bars = 500, the message would read "You are very happy". If the total of all 5 slide bars = 100 the message would read "You are very sad"

I'm new to this so looking for some experience and best practice advice so I can take it and learn.

```
$(function () {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 10,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
});
```

In the HTML, the results of the slider are showing like this:

```
<p>
    <label for="amount">Volume:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-    weight: bold;"
    />
</p>
<div id="slider-vertical" style="height: 200px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p>
    <label for="amount">Volume:</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>
<style>
    .slider { height: 200px; float:left; margin-right:20px; }
</style>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>
<div class="slider"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".slider" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 10,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var total = 0;
            $('.slider').each( function() {
                total += $(this).slider('value');
            });
            $( "#amount" ).val( total );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**ADDITION:**

In order to show different images depending on total value, you should, firstly, use image tag instead of input tag

```
<img id="amount-img" src="/path/to/images/defualt.png"/>
```

and, secondly, use code like this to choose and display images:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.slider').each( function() {
        total += $(this).slider('value');
    });

    var img = 'default.png';
    if( total>=50 ) img = 'above50.png';
    else if( total>=100 ) img = 'above100.png';
    else if( total>=250 ) img = 'above250.png';

    $('#amount-img').attr( 'src', '/path/to/images/'+img );
}
```

Comment: And you are probably misusing `input` - it is not to display messages, but to capture user input. You can set contents of _any_ html element dynamically - just use `.text(msg)` or `.html(msg)` instead of `.val(msg)`

Comment: Thanks Mas. Actually what I want the output to be is an image. How would I achieve that?

Comment: It is easy! Just choose image name based on `total` and then use `$('#image-id').attr('src',selected_name);` to change `src` attribute of `img`-tag and so the image beeing displayed. Reflected this in the answer.

Comment: So cool! cheers man, I'll take this and work with it! your a legend